# Codeception TeamCity integration

Tags: teamcity, codeception, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-9.1

I run this command line build step:

```
cd ../common && php ../../../vendor/bin/codecept --xml --no-exit run
```

In build log i have my tests output. I use `codeception` for my tests and i found only `phpunit` [meta runner](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/blob/master/php/MRPP_PHP_PHPUnit.xml) for `teamcity`.

I want to fail build if tests are failed, and any solution will happy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i use this command:

```
codecept --steps --xml --no-interaction --debug --no-ansi --no-colors run
```

For tests integration need use `--steps` and `--xml` parameter for xml report output. For setup report processing go to **Build Configuration Settings** -> **Build Features** and add `XML report processing` (Ant JUnit format).

With `--no-exit` teamcity will mark build as success anyway, so i removed it.